# Get the number of records of data in the current month

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to find the total number of records of the vehicles that ended in the current month in my database. I do not know what I should write in the `InvoiceDate` section in this case.

```cs
public void MonthlyStatus(NetContext context)
{
    var monthlyStatus = (from car in context.CarInformation
        where car.CurrentSituation== "Finish" && car.InvoiceDate == 
        select car);

    if (monthlyStatus == null)
    {
        label1.Text = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(monthlyStatus);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide the query to filter based on `Month` and `Year`.

```cs
var monthlyCount = (from car in context.CarInformation
    where car.CurrentSituation== "Finish" 
        && car.InvoiceDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
        && car.InvoiceDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year 
    select car)
    .Count();

label1.Text = Convert.ToString(monthlyCount);
```

Note that, your current LINQ query is not executed without [materialize (immediate execution) the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-a-collection-of-objects).

Side note, the COUNT query can be written in method syntax with [`Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-count-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))):

```cs
var monthlyCount = context.CarInformation
    .Count(car => car.CurrentSituation== "Finish" 
        && car.InvoiceDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
        && car.InvoiceDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year);
```

---

As suggested by @Svyatoslav Danyliv, to utilize the index usage by providing the date range filter, it should be:

```cs
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonth(1);

var monthlyCount = (from car in context.CarInformation
    where car.CurrentSituation== "Finish" 
        && car.InvoiceDate >= startDate
        && car.InvoiceDate < endDate 
    select car)
    .Count();
```

Comment: While it is correct it completely disable index usage. Consider to use date range instead.

Comment: Hi Svyatoslav, thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Thanks to you, I learned something.